# Getting access to HttpContext in class libaray through custom middlewear c# Asp.net 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

If we want access to HttpContext in a class library we can simple pass it like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebAppLib;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public class WebAppMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public WebAppMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            Test test = new test();
            test.TestMethod(httpContext) <--- passing the current httpcontext to the method.

            // Return httpcontext
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class WebAppMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseWebAppMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<WebAppMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

My Class library dll file(with FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" in csproj file)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebAppLib
{
    public class Test
    {
        public void TestMethod(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("hello from haldner");
            // continue with context instance
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's other ways this can be done? Basically I want to avoid passing "httpContext" to my method that i run in my custom middlewear.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid passing the HttpContext to it, if the method needs it? What underlying issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have multiple classes that needs access to httpcontext and it would be nice to avoid having to pass httpcontext to all of them in a parameter like MyMethodCall(HttpContext httpcontext) .. and just being able to call MyMethod()... but not sure if thats actually possible for the dll to get the current httpcontext without it.

Comment: As far as I know, `HttpContext` is not accessible except where provided or injected by the framework. Passing as a parameter is valid, though you might want to be extra careful about checking status of `Response` before writing to it.

Comment: Here is an article on [Accessing HttpContext outside of framework components in ASP.NET Core](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/) (relates to Brando's answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please tell me how you want to use this WebAppLib? Will you inject this class into the startup.cs?

If you will inject, then you could use other service inside the asp.net application. Like httpcontextaccessor or else to achieve your requirement. If you don't inject it and you don't want to pass httpcontext into it, you couldn't get it.

Details about how to use it, like this:

inject:

```
 services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

MyDependency class:

```
public class MyDependency : IMyDependency
{

    private IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    public MyDependency(IHttpContextAccessor context) {
        _context = context;

    }


    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        var path=  _context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

        Console.WriteLine($"MyDependency.WriteMessage Message: {message}");
    }
}
```